# How to remove duplicate in a list of tuples

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples, defaultdict

I have been trying around with defaultdict / dictionary set to remove the duplicate, however, I could not achieved desired output. I will demonstrate with more details below. I wish to remove duplicate in the list of tuple below:

```
List of tuples: [('Samsung', 'Handphone'), ('Samsung', 'Handphone),('Samsung','Tablet'),('Sony','Handphone')]
```

My desired output will be:

```
Output: {('Samsung','Handphone','Tablet'),('Sony','Handphone')}
```

I would like remove those duplicate values in the tuple and append "tablet" together with the "Samsung" in a tuple as it belongs to the same company. I have tried using defaultdict / dictionary. However I could not get it. How do i go about doing it? I would like to welcome any suggestions or ideas that you have. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cco said, your desired output is not possible, if you want to do further analysis with your dictionary then having keys and values is the best idea,

Try this,

```
from collections import defaultdict
a=[('Samsung', 'Handphone'), ('Samsung', 'Handphone'),('Samsung','Tablet'),('Sony','Handphone')]
a=list(set(a))
final={}
dic=defaultdict(list)
for k,v in a:
    dic[k].append(v)

for l,m in dic.iteritems():
    final[l]=m
print final
```

Output:

```
{'Sony': ['Handphone'], 'Samsung': ['Tablet', 'Handphone']}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind reply. For future analysis, your code is more useful by assigning key and values to company and its product respectively. I understand first part of your code. However, at your second half of your code, can I ask how does "dict.iteritems()" works? Also, may I ask how does "final[l]=m" works? Thank you!

Comment: `dict.iteritems()` Return an iterator over the dictionary’s (key, value) pairs. `final[l]=m` is a way to add key and values to the dictionary. In list we use `append`, but dictionary is different, so we have to give the key and values. `l` is key and `m` are values corresponding to it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Great explanation. I understood now. Thank you, Mr Shanmugam.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
t0 = [('Samsung', 'Handphone'), ('Samsung', 'Handphone'),('Samsung','Tablet'),('Sony','Handphone')]
for t in t0:
    d.setdefault(t[0], set()).add(t[1])
print(tuple(tuple([k]+list(v)) for k, v in d.items()))
```

which prints

```
(('Sony', 'Handphone'), ('Samsung', 'Handphone', 'Tablet'))
```

which is about as close to your desired output as I can come (your exact request isn't possible, since `{}` literals contain either dictionaries or sets, and printing a set literal with these tuples as content gives this:

```
set([('Sony', 'Handphone'), ('Samsung', 'Handphone', 'Tablet')])
```

which isn't what you asked for, although it is the same as the set literal

```
{('Sony', 'Handphone'), ('Samsung', 'Handphone', 'Tablet')}
```

Comment: Hi CCO, thanks for your kind reply. As I am still new to python, I am still unfamiliar on how list, tuple and dictionary works. Thanks for your kind explanation. I got a better understanding on how does dictionaries works with list and tuple. Thank you!